# Use a regular expression but keep what was replaced?

Tags: java, regex

I need a regular expression to remove certain characters but preserve what was removed into a new string. I'm hoping to avoid using two separate expressions.

Example,
Lets say I want to remove all numbers from a string but preserve them and place them in a different string.
"a1b23c" would become "abc" AND a new string for "123"

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Take a look at capture groups.

Comment: I think you would best handle this by using copying or cutting function with a regular expression instead of a removing with the regular expression.  that way you can keep it in memory and then store it in a variable.

Comment: see [this answer](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/2349/106356)

Comment: show us your regular expressions

Comment: I don't know Java, but in general languages, you can pass a function that takes the matched text as argument, add it to another string and returns empty to be replaced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing simple things like removing digits, it would be easier to use a pair of `StringBuilder`s:

```
StringBuilder digits = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder nonDigits = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) {
  char ch = str.charAt(i);
  if (Character.isDigit(ch) {
    digits.append(ch);
  } else {
    nonDigits.append(ch);
  }
}
System.out.println(nonDigits);
System.out.println(digits);
```

Comment: I guess you are right. Maybe I was over thinking the problem. My actual problem is to get the letters out ... isLetter.. Thanks. I guess Capture groups would be the way to do it with regex as lbarros said in comments above but that wouldn't be efficient in this case I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you describe with a find / replace loop using `Matcher.appendReplacement()` and `Matcher.appendTail()`.  For your example:

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher("a1b23c");
StringBuffer nonDigits = new StringBuffer();
StringBuffer digits = new StringBuffer();

while (matcher.find()) {
    digits.append(matcher.group());
    matcher.appendReplacement(nonDigits, "");
}
matcher.appendTail(nonDigits);

System.out.println(nonDigits);
System.out.println(digits);
```

Output:

```
abc
123
```

You do have to use `StringBuffer` instead of `StringBuilder` for this approach, because that's what `Matcher` supports.